# Do list iterators to map<int, list<double>> remain valid after map insertions/deletions?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, containers

std::list iterators remain valid under insertions and deletions. This is not the case for std::map iterators. I wonder if list iterators to objects of the type map<int, list> remain valid after map insertions/deletions.

Here is an example to better illustrate my question.

```cpp
std::map<int, std::list<double>> my_map;

// will this iterator remain valid if I insert into or delete from my_map?
auto it = my_map[0].begin();
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The basic rule is: if a container is mutated, iterators are invalidated.  Except when they're not.  You probably want to know when they are not.  It's a bit nuanced.  [Iterator invalidation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Iterator_invalidation)

Comment: This is not true for all types. For example, list iterators are not invalidated, hence the question. "Adding, removing and moving the elements within the list or across several lists does not invalidate the iterators or references. An iterator is invalidated only when the corresponding element is deleted." (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)

Comment: On insert yes. On delete yes, except for iterators referencing deleted items.

Comment: Of course. The question is, if I "wrap" the lists in a map (see example), will the list iterators still remain valid? My intuition says "yes" but I cannot justify it logically

Comment: If you update a mapped key with a new list iterators to the previous list are invalidated since it is destroyed even if the list is otherwise identical. I suppose that is obvious or should be.

Answer (score 2):

`std::map` invalidates iterators on insert/delete but it never invalidates references to the objects themselves - except the ones that are being deleted ofcourse.

So the `lists` and their iterators remain untouched.